# Yii2 how to retrieve foreign key in user table

Tags: php, yii2

I have been able to make login function for my website. But my user information consist of 2 tables.

```
usex -->    usex_id, user_id, passwd

user_group -->  usex_id, group_id
```

How can i retrieve group_id in Yii::$app->user->identity?

Thanks 
here is my `loginform.php` and `user.php`

Comment: You should simply add corresponding relation in your user model...

Comment: i mean in a controller or a view. if i want to print user_id, i simply call Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id right? but how about my foreign key with userGroups relation?